# Checking network data in android

Tags: android

By the following code i will be able to know Network connection is present there or not

```
    ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

But i want to know if actual data packets are there are not any help is much appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you want to know if the device is **actually** connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if ((wifi != null && wifi.isConnected())
                    || (mobile != null && mobile.isConnected()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            log("Connection", "Connection failed");
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using are telling you that  the device is connected to a network but not to the internet. **You can't know if it's actually connected to the internet without contacting any API.** That means you can't tell for sure if your app can reach your web service until you receive a valid response from it.

Comment: Yeah how i may know that if there is data coming or not

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following method to check internet connection

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {



    try{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean s= activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        return s;
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("exception network"+e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to get http response codes.

I used code similar to this in my project.

**DetectConnection.java** :-

```
package packagename;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class DetectConnection {
    public static boolean checkInternetConnection(){
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://google.com");// or replace this URL with a light-weight fast loading webpage
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            return code >= 200 && code < 300;
        }
        catch (IOException ioException){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity.java** :-

```
        AtomicBoolean isConnected = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        CompletableFuture<Void> cf= CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            if (DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection()) {
                /* TODO
                Code to be executed on success to load within 3 seconds.
                */
                isConnected.set(true);
            }
        });
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(() -> {
            try {
                sleep(3000); //you may adjust time here
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.i("Oh No", "Interrupted Exception", e);
            }
            cf.cancel(true);
            if (!isConnected.get()) {
                /* TODO
                Code to be executed when failed to load within 3 seconds.
                */
            }
        });
```